Scene builder failing to display custom TableView compiled with Java 17
I'm working on a javafx application so naturally I've had to use Scene Builder to display and manipulate fxml files. Everything seemed to be working fine until I decided to create a custom TableView and add it to the fxml file.
For the SDK, I'm using Zulu 17 packaged with javafx. For Scene Builder, I installed Scene Builder 21.0.0 which should be compatible with Java 17 according to the official website where they've stated that "You can use this Scene Builder version together with Java 17 and higher."
Now, in Intellij IDE, I've made sure to manually point to the Scene Builder executable which I installed because I didn't want the IDE to use any built-in Scene Builder (if there's any):

Next, I created a custom class which directly extends TableView, I called it ReportTableView and I imported it into my fxml file:
<?import com.application.ui.component.table.ReportTableView?>
Then added it as a component:
<ReportTableView fx:id="reportTableView" prefHeight="385.0" prefWidth="791.0">
    <VBox.margin>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
    </VBox.margin>
</ReportTableView>

So far, no compile errors are being shown and I'm actually able to add an instance field referencing this component to my controller class and run the application without any issues:
@FXML
private ReportTableView reportTableView;

The only issue I'm facing is when trying to switch to the Scene Builder tab of the fxml file editor. I'm getting the exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/application/ui/component/table/ReportTableView has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0


Which is a bit weird. I know that the ReportTableView class is being compiled using Java 17, which can be confirmed by the exception message itself (class compiled with version 61.0), and I know that the Scene Builder executable is compatible with Java 17 and I explicitly pointed to it from the javafx settings as mentioned above, so I'm not sure why the exception is still referencing major version 55.0 (Java 8).
I also tried invalidating caches + restarting Intellij which didn't make a difference.
What's weirder is that Scene Builder has no problem displaying other built-in javafx components which are obviously also compiled with Java 17 since they're part of the Zulu 17 SDK.
What could the issue be?

"so naturally I've had to use SceneBuilder" is simply not correct. You can very easily hand code your layouts and leave the whole FXML and SceneBuilder nightmare in the past.

Recommended workflow for FXML with Idea

when trying to switch to the Scene Builder tab of the fxml file editor

Don’t do that.
The Scene Builder tab in Idea doesn't use a downloaded SceneBuilder at all (I think), it uses an embedded SceneBuilderKit (which with your IDE version is built for Java 8, based on your information on class file version mismatches).
Either:

Open Scene Builder by clicking an icon on the desktop then, in Scene Builder, select a file to edit.

Or

In Idea, right-click the fxml file and select “Open in SceneBuilder” to open in the external app.

Use a recent stable Idea version.

Now, in Intellij IDE, I've made sure to manually point to the Scene Builder executable which I installed because I didn't want the IDE to use any built-in Scene Builder (if there's any):

Yes, but I think the IDE will only use that manual configuration when you right-click the file and choose "Open in SceneBuilder", otherwise it uses its inbuilt SceneBuilderKit (when you choose the Scene Builder tab in the IDE while editing the FXML).
Advice
Using a custom component of your design in SceneBuilder is a pretty involved process.

JavaFX custom component usage in SceneBuilder

You haven't performed many of the steps documented in the related question and answer which would allow a custom component to be used in SceneBuilder.  And for the embedded SceneBuilderKit in Idea, I don't even know if there is a way to configure it to be able to use a custom control.
If you don’t want to do the setup of importing your custom component into SceneBuilder (and require other project developers to do the same), then you could remove the custom component reference from your FXML.
You can keep using FXML for other things but add your custom component in the Java code. In your example, it looks like your ReportTableView is in a VBox, so you could create an instance of ReportTableView in your controller's initialize method and add it to the VBox instead of having that tiny bit of work done in FXML.
